# SDWebImage - how to load image from Cache?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimage, sdwebimage

I use `SDWebImage` to download images into my `UITableView` using:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tempPhotoURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"temp.jpg"]];
```

This works perfectly - no problem there. But when I click on any given row in my TableView, I want to load  that row's thumbnail-image into a `UIImageView` that's sitting in the oncoming detail-screen to which I'm navigating. Well how do I do this? Do I now have to get the image from the cache since its already been downloaded? If so, what's the method/process for this? And if that's not the way to go, what is?
I can't figure it out from all those files and methods included in the `SDWebImage` library...

Answer (score 1):

Simply use almost exactly same code to set the image - SDWebImage will check if it is already cached and if so, it will use it instead of fetching image from the url.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
   [self.imgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl placeholderImage:placeholderUrl options:0 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

//Progress block

} completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL){
             //Completion block
         }];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve things when coding.
One that springs to mind is to ensure the UIImageView is an accessible property  of your detail view controller (part of the detail view controller's API).
Then all you need to do is before you push your detail view controller, assign the cell's image view to the detail view's UIImageView property.

OR

create a convenience initialiser and pass the cell's imageview to it...
etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Call the same method, you downloaded with in your `TableView` in `DetailView` when you set the picture, it will check the cache first. Here's the code snippet to download image with `SDWebImage`

```
[yourImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourImageUrl]
                          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"]];
```